# Unable to see elements of std::vector with gcc in VS Code

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm currently using VS Code to learn C++ because it was easy to setup and is much lighter than VS Studio. However, one thing that I'm unable to do is to see the elements of an array (or string, etc), in debug mode.

[image: vector]

I've searched for solutions here, and it seems that enabling pretty printing would solve the issue, but unfortunately it did not (I have Python 3.6 installed).

I've also tried using VS Studio compiler and debugger, but was unable to get it to work the way I wanted (basically clicking F5 to compile single cpp files without needing to change any options, just a single click).

What can I try next? I'm currently using MinGW compiler on Windows 10, with the following tasks file:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o", "example"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

and launch:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/example.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "preLaunchTask": "echo",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue on my mac. Looks like a bug in VS Code

Comment: But have you managed to find a workaround? maybe with another debugger? _I've tried this one [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) but didn't find it helpful

Comment: My work-around is to look inside the vector. Add a watch and type something like this: `(int(*)[5])ints._M_impl._M_start` (I am using a different implementation of STL so my expression is a little bit different). The `_M_start` points to the storage inside vector. Cast it to an array and you get the elements

Comment: When vscode shows `{...}` sometimes it is actually "working". It could either be mean there are zero elements or it's broken. Hard to establish trust. I wish it would show the number of elements when it knew.

Answer (score 6):

For me this works, but check first if you have `'c:\msys64\mingw64\share\gcc-8.3.0\python'` or `'c:\usr\share\gcc-8.3.0\python'` folder and adjust the snippet

`launch.json`

```
...
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "python import sys;sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\\msys64\\mingw64\\share\\gcc-8.3.0\\python');from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
...
```

Comment: this worked for me, just changed python path to /usr/bin/python (for remote linux debug)

Comment: I think just `python register_libstdcxx_printers(None)` should be enough.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me in a remote linux machine.

Please check the path '/usr/share/gcc-10/python' on your server. It might be different for you.

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "python import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/share/gcc-10/python');sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/bin/python');from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)",
        "ignoreFailures": false
    },
    {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Windows**:

If you only see memory address for STL containers when debugging, you probably used x64 Windows.

I found one valid solution, when installing MinGW in x64 Windows, install `i686 (win32)` version (the bottom of this comment gives its official download link) of MinGW instead of `x86_64` version, see below:

[image: pretty-printing-not-work-with-MinGW GDB-solution]

**win32 version of MinGW download:**

[i686-win32-dwarf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-win32/dwarf/i686-8.1.0-release-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0.7z)

I just extracted the downloaded file into the folder `D:\MinGW`, then add the bin path of MinGW `D:\MinGW\i686-8.1.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin` to the `PATH` of System Variable of environment.

[image: Add MinGW to system variable]

#### The related config files are below:

`.vscode\tasks.json`

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            // "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

`.vscode\launch.json`

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {   // Display content in STL containers pretty
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

`.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json`

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "g++", // Or complete absolute path "D:/MinGW/i686-8.1.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe"
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

### Environment of my PC

```
VSCode Version: 1.53.2 (system setup)
OS Version: Windows 10 x64 (Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041)
MinGW version: i686-8.1.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0
GDB version: 8.1.0 (Target: i686-w64-mingw32)
```

Initially posted on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3921#issuecomment-780379258.

May it be helpful for you.

Comment: this works nicely

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar problem using `MinGW` for Windows.

Problem was resolved for me when I removed `MINGW` and installed [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) instead.

Comment: " Mingw-w64 is an advancement of the original mingw.org project, created to support the GCC compiler on Windows systems. " as written on the website.

Answer (score 1):

I used the method just like Georgy described above.

```
*((int(*)[10])array._M_impl._M_start)

Debug console output:
-exec p array
$7 = {<std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x2924cb0, _M_finish = 0x2924cd8, _M_end_of_storage = 0x2924cf0}}, <No data fields>}

-exec p *((int(*)[10])array._M_impl._M_start)
$8 = {41, 18467, 6334, 26500, 19169, 15724, 11478, 29358, 26962, 24464}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to a python issue with gdb. I recommend to use msys2 + mingw. It work fine and you get last version of gcc.
How to install mingw with msys2:

- install msys2
- pacman -Suy
- pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
- pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
- pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-make
- add 'D:\msys64\mingw64\bin' to path ENV

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, eventually using [user3324131 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67879283/158371) with a tiny modification I was able to get it to install to the right place:

- Install msys2
- `$pacman -Suy`
- `$pacman -Suy mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` (note the `-Suy`)
- `$pacman -Suy mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb` (note the `-Suy`)
- `$pacman -Suy mingw-w64-x86_64-make` (note the `-Suy`)
- Add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to path ENV
- Reopen vscode, and all works

Here is the result:
[image]

AMAZING, Thanks and Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, and was able to solve it using the first two comments from this [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1414).

1. create a file `~/.gdbinit` and place the following in the file and replace the path to python to your actual python install (line 3) (Documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport)).

```py
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/c/Python310')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

2. In your `launch.json` add a `setupCommands` object.:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Output]