# vscode gdb debug console could not find operator [ ]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, debug-console

when i use vscode debug console to debug cpp code as gdb, i want to print the std::vector's element. as the pic below, i can print the vector(in_tensors), but when i want to print the vector's element, the debug console say could not find operator.how can i do?  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Hqm.png)

how can i use vscode debug console as a gdb?

Comment: what compile flags did you use?

Comment: Do you have the libraries for gdb to resolve the vector type?

Comment: Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72612534/4690576)?

Comment: i use camke and no more flags.Additional, only when i use gdbserver will be like this.