Cannot view contents of std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> in VSCode C++ Debugger
I'm trying to debug a program in C++.
For some reason, I'm unable to see the contents of a std::vector of pointers in the VSCode debugger. The vector appears in the debugger, but I can't inspect the actual objects or their details. How can I resolve this and view the contents clearly?
This is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int id) : id(id) {}
    void display() const { std::cout << "Object ID: " << id << std::endl; }

private:
    int id;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> myObjects;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
        myObjects.push_back(std::make_shared<MyClass>(i));
    }
    
    for (const auto& obj : myObjects) {
        obj->display();
    }

    return 0;
}

launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/home/my_user/project/build/test",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

And this is what I see, when I'm trying to examine the vector of pointers:

I compile in debug mode:
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
I can see the id of only the first element in the vector.
How can I view the full contents of a std::vectorstd::shared_ptr<MyClass> clearly in the VSCode debugger?

I see the vector contents correctly, using MSYS2 MinGW and GDB. I guess your version of MinGW doesn't have GDB pretty-printers?

vector is too complicated for the generic variable viewer to handle. You need what's called a "Pretty Printer" that knows how to interpret vector for the Standard Library implementation you are using (different versions of the library often do things at least a little differently) and display the interpreted results. Once you find or write the appropriate Pretty Printer, you'll probably want to do the same thing for std::string.

@user4581301 Printers for standard types should be shipped by default with libstdc++, and OP's launch.json even enables them. Not sure why -enable-pretty-printing doesn't work for them, but it does for me.

The pretty printers are python code, yes? Perhaps no python.

Just ran a sick experiment. After setting up msys, mingw, and Eclipse because I'm more familiar with it, pretty printing wasn't working, so I fired up a msys console, installed python with pacman -S python, and whammo! Pretty printing working. Can't guarantee that it'll work for you, but it's something to look into.

I use linux, when I debug in clion I do see the variables clearly. Also, I tried to setup a new project just with this file, and it works in vscode. For some reason, it happens only on my project

found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828562/unable-to-see-elements-of-stdvector-with-gcc-in-vs-code.
Added this and it solved it:
{
"description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
"text": "python import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/share/gcc/python');sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/bin/python');from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)",
"ignoreFailures": false
},
